# For the below script to delete files in a directory that are more than 10 mins old, I get the error to assign creation time os.path.getctime

Tags: python, python-2.7

Code:

```
import os
import time

trigger_file_dir = "/appl/wsl/itws/test"
log_file_path = "/appl/wsl/itws/stale_files.log"

# Get the current time
current_time = time.time()

# List all files in the directory
files = os.listdir(trigger_file_dir)

# Iterate over the files
for file in files:
    file_path = os.path.isfile(os.path.join(trigger_file_dir, file))

    # Get the creation time of the file
    creation_time = os.path.getctime(file_path)

    # Check if the file was created more than 10 minutes ago
    if current_time - creation_time > 600:

        # Write the file name and timestamp to the log
        log_entry = {time.ctime(creation_time)} - {file}
        with open(log_file_path, "a") as log_file:
            log_file.write(str(log_entry))

        # Delete the file
        os.remove(file_path)
```

1)to delete files in a directory that are more than 10 mins old
2)To ignore the other sub-directories present.
3)to log the file name and time in a log file before deleting the file

Comment: And what error would that be?

Comment: @shubinaidu: that's not an error message of the code in your question.

Comment: file_path will be either True or False. Neither are viable arguments to os.path.getctime()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`os.path.getctime(file_path)` is trying to get the creation time of a boolean value. That should probably be `file` or `os.path.join(trigger_file_dir, file)`. Your choice of variable names confuses yourself. Same for `os.remove(file_path)`.

Suggestion:

```py
for file in files:
    file_path = os.path.join(trigger_file_dir, file)
    isfile = os.path.isfile(file_path)
    if not isfile:
        continue
[...]
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/appl/wsl/bin/remove_stagetriggerfiles.py", line 19, in <module>
    creation_time = os.path.getctime(isfile)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/genericpath.py", line 64, in getctime
    return os.stat(filename).st_ctime
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, bool found

Comment: `os.path.getctime(isfile)` this does not make sense. Why are you passing a boolean to that function? It's the same mistake as before, except that it's even more obvious now due to the variable name. You must pass a file name to it, such as `file_path`. Just copy and paste the code I wrote. Don't modify it. Understand it.